# not seeing UDP multicast messages from another device

Tags: python, python-3.x, interface, udp, multicast

I have a Windows machine where I have two scripts that send and receive messages via UDP multicast (on the same machine). I have a C and Python3 implementation of this. The Python3 one looks like this:

sender.py

```
import socket

MCAST_GRP = '239.1.1.1'
MCAST_PORT = 1234

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, 2)
print("Sending")
sock.sendto(bytearray("str()", "utf-8"), (MCAST_GRP, MCAST_PORT))

data, address = sock.recvfrom(1024)
print('received %s bytes from %s' % (len(data), address))
print(data)
```

receiver.py

```
import socket
import struct
import sys

multicast_group = '239.1.1.1'
server_address = ('', 1234)

# Create the socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Bind to the server address
sock.bind(server_address)

# Tell the operating system to add the socket to the multicast group
# on all interfaces.
group = socket.inet_aton(multicast_group)
mreq = struct.pack('4sL', group, socket.INADDR_ANY)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

# Receive/respond loop
while True:
    print('\nwaiting to receive message')
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(1024)

    print('received %s bytes from %s' % (len(data), address))
    print(data)

    print('sending acknowledgement to', address)
    sock.sendto(bytearray("ack", "utf-8"), address)
```

I have another physical device hooked up to the same machine but I cannot receive any messages from it with my programs. I can see that Wireshark is seeing the messages from the other physical device, these messages are coming over the `eth0` interface to the same IP and Port. I know that the traffic generated by my scripts is on the `VirtualBox Host-Only Network`. I am not sure if that could cause the issue of me not seeing the UDP multicast messages from the external device.

I have tested it on a Linux machine as well (latest kali version) but could not receive any messages from the external device as well.

If I am missing some information, please let me know.

**EDIT 1:**

My setup is as follows:
I am running a native Windows 10 machine. To this machine is a device connected that is running some OS I don't know. I am only able to send and receive messages from it. I can send Ethernet, TCP, and IPv4 packets over the physical ethernet port on my Windows 10 machine by specifying the software I am using for this to use eth0 and a defined IP(v4) address I assigned to that port in the network adapter settings (192.168.1.100)

The scripts are running on the same Windows 10 machine that is also connected to the device. They are sending on this interface `VirtualBox Host-Only Network` but I don't know why. I did not configure anything like this. I assume that the interface should not be a problem because that is how UDP Multicast works (I am not sure of that so if I am mistaken please let me know!)

A sample output of the sender looks like this:

```
Sending
received 3 bytes from ('192.168.56.1', 3000)
b'ack'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

and the receiver:

```
waiting to receive message
received 5 bytes from ('192.168.56.1', 55132)
b'robot'
sending acknowledgement to ('192.168.56.1', 55132)

waiting to receive message
```

I hope that clarifies the setup. If there is still information missing please let me know!

Comment: Please try `sock.recvfrom(1)` rather than `sock.recvfrom(1024)`

Comment: What is the exact network configuration you are using?  You mention at least 3 possible machines (Windows host, VM and an external machine).  Where are you running your programs and what interfaces are you expecting to use?

Comment: @Penn changing from 1024 to 1 causes the receiver to crash. For Peter: I will update my question

Comment: @PeterBrittain I have updated my question and added some information

Comment: @JRsz What is the error? Does it crash after you send the bytes, or before?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As covered in https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Multicast-HOWTO-6.html, the sockets API requires that you identify the interface as well as the multicast address/port you want to use.

By not specifying this in your sample code, you have left this down to the OS to pick and it has picked a VirtualBox Host-Only Network.  Unfortunately this type of network is [limited to VMs running on the Windows machines](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html).

To fix it, you need to identify the interface that you want to use for the multicast and pass that in to your sending and receving code.  For example:

sender.py

```
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_IF, socket.inet_aton(MCAST_IF_IP))
```

receiver.py

```
mreq = struct.pack('4s4s', group, socket.inet_aton(MCAST_IF_IP))
```

where `MCAST_IF_IP` is the IP address of the interface that you want to use.

Comment: That worked, so it was the interface after all. Thank you very much! Well earned bounty! But I do have one more question: The receiver receives the packets from device only from the moment where my sender sends a message. From that on it receives every message but not before. Do you know why that is the case?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sorry, but I haven't a clue why you only see messages in the way you describe.  Posssibly worth asking separately to see if anyone else can help you....

Comment: Could you maybe check out this similar question as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50878441/python3-tcp-server-not-seeing-incoming-messages-from-external-device

Comment: this doesn't work in my virtual Windows 10 machine or natively in Ubuntu 20.04. the `sender.py` modification throws an exception `OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address`

Comment: the `receiver.py` modification causes an error as well in native linux: `OSError: [Errno 19] No such device`

Comment: The logic is based on the documentation and has been tested, so I'm expecting your erros are that you've picked the wrong IP address for your netqwork routing.