# Python3 TCP Server not seeing incoming messages from external device

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp, wireshark, tcpserver

I want to create a small TCP server that takes incoming TCP connections from a device that is hooked up via Ethernet to my computer.

The physical port for that has the IP `192.168.1.100` statically assigned to it.

The scripts I use as a client and server are listed at the bottom.

The setup works if I want to send messages between the python scripts. However, I am unable to receive anything from the external device (screenshot from Wireshark capture below). From what I have read I can define an interface to listen to by defining its IP. So I defined the IP of the interface as the `host` variable. However, I do not receive anything in my script but the messages sent by the other script. I had a similar situation already here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50469157/not-seeing-udp-multicast-messages-from-another-device). I thought that defining the correct IP as the host would resolve this issue but it did not.

I am also having a hard time capturing the traffic between the two scripts with Wireshark at all. They did not show up anywhere.

I need to pick up these connections on the `eth0` interface with the static IP `192.168.1.100`:

[image]

`tcp_server.py`

```
import socket

# create a socket object
serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# get local machine name
# host = socket.gethostname()
host = "192.168.1.100"

port = 9002

# bind to the port
serverSocket.bind((host, port))

# queue up to 5 requests
serverSocket.listen(5)

while True:
    # establish a connection
    clientSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()

    print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))

    msg = 'Thank you for connecting' + "\r\n"
    clientSocket.send(msg.encode('ascii'))
    clientSocket.close()
```

and this as a client:

`tcp_client.py`

```
import socket

# create a socket object
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# get local machine name
# host = socket.gethostname()
host = "192.168.1.100"

port = 9002

# connection to hostname on the port.
s.connect((host, port))

# Receive no more than 1024 bytes
msg = s.recv(1024)

s.close()
print(msg.decode('ascii'))
```

Comment: have you tried `serverSocket.bind(("", port))` to narrow down the problem? this will listen on all interfaces

Comment: For reasons I cannot explain, I could connect with similar code when listening on `('', 9002)`. The peer did have the physical card address and after that all worked fine, *including listening only on the physical address*...

Comment: @Fire I have tried that but it did not change anything. Still not receiving any messages

Comment: @SergeBallesta How do you listen only on a physical address?

Comment: Two questions spring to mind: (1) do you have any firewalls enabled and (2) how do you know that this other device is correctly connected to the network?  (See https://superuser.com/questions/614600/tcp-syn-does-not-reach-tcp-server for an example of a possibly related case...)

Comment: I'm wondering how this setup should work. I don't see your server-code `recv` anything. You're just accepting connections and sending the welcome. On the other side, your client does not send anything.